# No mounted sdcard when storing a file in the sdcard

Tags: android, file-io

I have a file in the `/data/data<package name>/files/settings.dat` and want to store/copy this file in the sdcard, the file is well readed but when trying to copy it to the sdcard, i have an exception: sdacrd is not mounted.
I added the right line to the androidmanifest.xml and added a virtual sdcard in the emulator. `-sdcard /Users/Alaeddine/Documents/workspace/android_sdcard`
Code:

```
public void transfer(){
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if(!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) 
    {
       Log.d("Carburant", "Sdcard was not mounted !!" ); 
    }
  else
    {
      File nmea_file; 
      File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
      FileWriter nmea_writer = null;
      try {
          nmea_file = new File(root,"settings.dat");
          if(!nmea_file.exists()) {
                  Log.w("Carburant", "File Doesn't Exists!");
                  nmea_file.createNewFile();
              }
    copyfile(nom,sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + nmea_file);
      }
      catch (IOException e) 
      {
          Log.w("Carburant", "Unable to write", e);
      } 
      finally 
      {
          if (nmea_writer != null) 
          {
              try 
              {
                  nmea_writer.close();
              } 
              catch (IOException e) 
              {
                  Log.w("Carburant", "Exception closing file", e);
              }
          }
      }
    }

}
```

How can i solve this problem ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't mounted the sdcard to your computer while plugged in and forgot to unmount it while running your app? I do that sometimes and forget about it...

Edit: Oops sorry didnt realize you were using the emulator. You can go into the settings on the emulator and check to make sure the sdcard is mounted. If that doesn't work look up creating and mounting a virtual sdcard on the emulator from the command line.

Comment: the title of the question says "permission denied" but your text says "sdacrd is not mounted".  Can you state exactly what the error is please?

Comment: @dave.c: you have reason, i edited the title.

Comment: ok, so is the code throwing an exception or is `if(!Environment.getExternalStorageState()...` returning `false` and you get `Sdcard was not mounted !!` in your log?

Comment: @dave.c: the second option. it's giving this exception just when it checks if the sdcard is mounted or not.

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually define a sdcard in the emulator at all? You need to define it when creating the AVD in the AVD manager application (but you can modify an existing AVD and add an sd card later).

On unix you can start the AVD manager via

```
$ android
```

given that the android-sdk/tools folder is in your path.

See also http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/index.html for this.

Comment: @Heiko Rupp: yes i think this command adds an sdcard! i verified in the settings-Storage and it indicates all unavailable, so there is not an sdcard! so, how to add a virtual one ?

Comment: run the `android` command to list the virtual devices and check if the device has an sdcard defined. It is possible to create devices without (or with size 0).

Comment: @Heiko Rupp: where i put the commands ? sorry but i'm not understanding your idea.

Comment: This was meant on a unix shell -b I guess there is a way from within Eclipse to start this AVD manager too. Or in Windows from Explorer by starting android-sdk-*\tools\android.exe. Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/index.html

Comment: @Heiko Rupp: Yes, there is android.exe in the tools directory. I execute it and i have a command line window! What the command to put to see if there is an sdcard ?

Comment: @Heikp Rupp: I re-created an sdcard, i followed this link and no sdcard available:http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/33240.aspx

Comment: @Heiko Rupp: Any idea please?

Comment: After pointing you to http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html I am out of ideas.